# Load XML into mySQL with diffrent rows ID

Tags: mysql, xml, import

I have the following XML file and I need load into mysql using LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE.

I´m using the following line:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:/_BORBA_/xml/importxml.xml' INTO TABLE importxml ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<ide>'
```

If I declare "**ide**" as delimiter, I can import with sucess, but I have to import all tags (ide, info and proc) as one record row.

How can I explicit that I have 3 groups of information into my XML file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<infNFe versao="3.10" Id="NFe351710006">
    <ide>
        <cUF>35</cUF>
        <cNF>99999</cNF>
        <natOp>Venda de terceiros</natOp>
        <indPag>1</indPag>
        <mod>55</mod>
        <serie>1</serie>
        <nNF>888888</nNF>
        <dhEmi>2017-10-26T16:50:52-02:00</dhEmi>
    </ide>  
    <info>
        <tpNF>1</tpNF>
        <idDest>2</idDest>
        <cMunFG>3525904</cMunFG>
        <tpImp>1</tpImp>
        <tpEmis>1</tpEmis>
    </info>
    <proc>
        <cDV>8</cDV>
        <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
        <finNFe>1</finNFe>
        <indFinal>0</indFinal>
        <indPres>9</indPres>
        <procEmi>3</procEmi>
        <verProc>008</verProc>
        <CNPJ>99999888844</CNPJ>
    </proc> 
</infNFe>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible, [LOAD XML](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html) does not support different tags as one row. Do you have anything else at your disposal besides SQL?

Comment: Thank you Peter, I have an alternative that is create a PHP or Pyhton script, but I was trying to avoid this option. :(

Comment: Unless someone smarter does know of a way I'm afraid that's what you're stuck with.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I´m trying since yesterday to find a way to do this f%$# import ... lol

Comment: Creating a simple parser would've been a lot easier :-)